# How Kill the top 3 consuming process in Linux?

Tags: bash

I want to kill the 3 process the consuming the `CPU` so i have this code:

```
topmem='80'
topcpu='60'
file='/tmp/proc_consuming.txt'


if [[ "$memuse" -ge "$topmem"  && "$cpuuse" -ge "$topcpu" ]];then
    top -b -n 1 | head | grep -A 4 PID >"$file"
fi

for i in 2 3 4
do
    echo "process" $(cat $file | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{if(NR=='$i') print $0}') "Killed"
done
```

considering `$memuse` and `$cpuuse` are variables for get **memory** and **cpu** usage, i just wondering is there any other way to `kill` the top 3 consuming process instead of this way ?

Answer (score 0):

For PID selection, I prefer:

```sh
top -b -n 1 | head -8 | tail -3 | awk '{print $1}'
```

I think a `grep PID` is too simple, too dangerous.

So:

```sh
for pid in $(top ...); do
    kill -9 "$pid"
    echo ...
donc
```